# Is it possible to transform all these pointers into array of pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have pointers like that. I don't know if I did this properly. I don't know how to allocate memory for them. Maybe the computer allocates memory automatically?

```
    char *d = "Array1";
    char *d1 = "Array2";
    char *e = "Sum array";
```

Is it possible to make an array of pointers like this:

```
char *names[] = {"Array1","Array2","Sum array"}
```

And how to use this pointers when I call a function?

I usually use (the second argument is my pointer):

```
writeArray(wc, e, n, arr2);
```

So when I use an array of pointers it will be something like that?

```
writeArray(wc, name[2], n, arr2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have pointers like that. I don't know if I did this properly. I don't know how to allocate memory for them. Maybe the computer allocates memory automatically?
>
> ```
> char *d = "Array1";
> char *d1 = "Array2";
> char *e = "Sum array";
> ```

The compiler will allocate an array of `char` with static storage duration for each string literal and initialize the variables to point to the first character of those `char` arrays.

> Is it possible to make an array of pointers like this:
>
> ```
> char *names[] = {"Array1","Array2","Sum array"}
> ```

Yes (although the declaration requires a semicolon), the compiler will set the length of the `names` array to 3 automatically to match the number of initializers since the length has not been specified explicitly.

As before, the compiler will allocate an array of `char` with static storage duration for each string literal. The compiler will initialize each element of the `names` array to point to the first character of those `char` arrays.

Since the contents of these string literals match those used to initialize the `d`, `d1` and `e` variable, the compiler *might* overlap the storage for the identical string literals. This is OK because C code must not modify the storage occupied by these string literals.

If `names[]` has *automatic* storage duration (in a function), you could declare and initialize it as follows, assuming `d`, `d1`, and `e` are already pointing to the correct string literals:

```
char *names[] = {d, d1, e};
```

Then the elements of `names[]` will be pointing to the exact same string literal `char` array storage as `d`, `d1` and `e`.

> And how to use this pointers when I call a function?
>
> I usually use (the second argument is my pointer):
>
> ```
> writeArray(wc, e, n, arr2);
> ```
>
> So when I use an array of pointers it will be something like that?
>
> ```
> writeArray(wc, name[2], n, arr2);
> ```

Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it possible to make an array of pointers like this*

Yes, it is.

> *So when I use an array of pointers it will be something like that?*

Correct.

Comment: Thank you so much - it works perfect! I also check my code in cppcheck and everything is ok.